# Why the resolution phase is required in Java during class loading?

Tags: java, jvm

When do the symbolic references gets replaced with memory references in method area?

Comment: Your question’s title asks “why” whereas the body asks “when”. Decide, what you are actually asking.

Answer (score 2):

All symbolic references that were now loaded into the method area in form of the runtime constant pool are resolved to actual types loaded by this JVM. If a symbolic reference can be resolved but results in a conflict of definitions, a `IncompatibleClassChangeError` is thrown. If a referenced class cannot be found, a `NoClassDefFoundError` is thrown which basically wraps a `ClassNotFoundException` that was thrown by the class loader attempting to load this referenced class. If a referenced class references itself, a `ClassCircularityError` is thrown. Resolution can happen in one of two flavors which is up to the implementors of the JVM

**Eager**: All symbolic references to other fields, methods or classes are resolved right now.

**Lazy**: Resolving of symbolic references is postponed until the first use of a method. This might bring with it that a class refering to a non-existant class never throws an error if this reference never needs to be resolved.

look at the beginning of the [Chapter 5.4.3.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.4.3) Resolution, there’s stated explicitly:

> The Java Virtual Machine instructions anewarray, checkcast, getfield,
> getstatic, instanceof, invokedynamic, invokeinterface, invokespecial,
> invokestatic, invokevirtual, ldc, ldc_w, multianewarray, new,
> putfield, and putstatic make symbolic references to the run-time
> constant pool. Execution of any of these instructions requires
> resolution of its symbolic reference.

There’s the resolving of the direct super class and the directly implemented interfaces (or super interfaces in case of an interface) which happens early and there’s the resolution of symbolic references for the purpose of the above byte code instructions which can be postponed.

Answer (score 0):

The resolution phase is required so that the referenced classes or interfaces are resolved either the first time they are used or all at once based on the JVM implementation.

**When do the symbolic references gets replaced with memory references in method area**

This happens as part of class file verification which works in conjunction with the class loader and it ensures that loaded class files have a proper internal structure and they are consistent.

Class file verification happens in four distinct passes:

- **Pass 1**: Structural checks on the class files

  This happens as a class is loaded. The loaded class is checked for the internal structure to ensure it is safe to parse.
- **Paas 2**: Semantic checks on the data type.

  Here class file verifier makes sure that semantics of Java programming lanuage is obeyed.
- **Pass 3**: Bytecode verification

  Here the data-flow analysis of the bytecodes representing the methods of the class is performed
- **Pass 4**: Verification of symbolic references

  **It is this pass 4 where the dynamic linking happens which is nothing but the process of resolving symbolic references into direct references.**